# Extremely Slow And/or Unreliable Wifi on a 2009 Macbook Pro With BCM4322

Tags: wireless, macbook

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my late-2009 Macbook Pro (7,1), I was experiencing very slow wifi speeds, sometimes dropping below 1 kb/s and never reaching much higher than 45 kb/s. I tried installing wicd and apt-get purge'ing network-manager, and my connection was actually fine for a little bit, until wicd started slowing down, too, and eventually stopped working altogether, so now I have no access to the internet on my Macbook other than ethernet.

I apt-get install'd linux-headers-generic, and then apt-get install'd bcmwl-kernel-source, and, when I tried to "sudo modprobe wl", I was shown the error:

"FATAL: Error inserting wl (/lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Invalid argument"

What am I doing wrong here? Should I install a different driver?

The results of "lspci -nn | grep 0280" are as follows:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11/a/b/g/n Wireless LAN controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some controversy about the best driver for this device. Let's try the first of two methods. Temporarily hook up the ethernet and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and let us hear from you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry for the late reply, but when I rebooted my computer after completing those two steps, I found my connection was as slow as ever. I tried purging wicd, installing network-manager, rebooting, and connecting to my router again, but network-manager was just as slow, with downloads averaging at about 1600 B/s. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Let's see: dmesg | grep -e eth1 -e wl

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GcFJNjNH

Comment: I notice this: "b43 ssb0:0: wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported" Please try a driver parameter: sudo modprobe -r b43; sudo modprobe -r ssb; sudo modprobe b43 qos=0  If it helps, we'll write a conf file and make it persistent. You might also try turning off N speeds in the router, if any.

Comment: Hm... It seems like "sudo modprobe b43 qos=0" didn't make too much of a difference, really, and my wifi still seems to be inconsistent, every now and then disconnecting and reconnecting on it's own, or forcing me to reconnect manually. Do you have any other suggestions? Also, forgive my obvious novice-ness, but how would I go about turning off N speeds on my router?

Comment: Go in to the administration pages of your router and look under Wireless. There should be an option to use B&G only or B, G & N. Change to B&G. Please see here: http://rakeshbera.com/winxp/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/netgear-wireless-settings-tab.jpg  In this example, the mode is set to G and B. You might also try a different channel from the default of 6. I have the best luck with 11.